# Cannot create subfolder on USB Disk, Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, mkdir

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on my Raspberry Pi 4. I need to record some data, therefore a plugged in a USB Stick to the PI and want to save the records to this location.
I checked the path via `mount`:

```
 /dev/sda1 on /media/ubuntu/USB DISK
```

So I set the `dataPath` of my application to: `media/ubuntu/USB DISK/records`.
Inside my application I have the following function:

```
time_t ct = time(0);
mkdir(dataPath.c_str(), S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH); //this works: creates /records on the disk
//chmod(dataPath.c_str(), 0777)

tm *ltm = localtime(&ct);
String timeStr = format("%i_%i_%i_%i:%i:%i", 1900+ltm->tm_year, 1+ltm->tm_mon
                       , ltm->tm_mday, 1+ltm->tm_hour, 1+ltm->tm_min, 1+ltm->tm_sec);
String fullPath = dataPath + "/" + timeStr;
const char *c = fullPath.c_str(); // /media/ubuntu/USB DISK/records/2020_6_15_8:30:3
auto f = mkdir(c, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
```

The first `mkdir` command, works and creates `/media/ubuntu/USB DISK/records/` on the usb disk.
But the second command, which should create `/media/ubuntu/USB DISK/records/2020_6_15_8:30:3` doesn't work. There is no subfolder in `records` directory.

I start the script with: `sudo ./main`

Any ideas, what might be the problem?

Comment: [colon ":" is special symbol in M$ (FAT / exFAT / NTFS) file systems](https://www.comentum.com/File-Systems-HFS-FAT-UFS.html) - try "%i_%i_%i_%i_%i_%i" .

Answer (score 0):

When naming folders and files you must remain within the file system's constraint's. The colon ':' you have in the name is invalid and should not be used in naming of folders (as mentioned in @Maxmim's comment). It is best to keep all folder names to alphanumeric characters including the additional hyphen and underscore. This allows for less complications if and when the files/folders are to be read on a different file system. Also, note capitalization as some systems are case-sensitive and others not (Windows vs. Raspbian/Linux for example).

Another naming system you could use is to substitute the hyphen for the colons and the date-time is still readable (e.g. 2020-12-17-1117-53) on Raspbian, Windows & Linux. This is the full timestamp up to the second (i.e. YYYY-mm-dd-HHMM-SS).

As for the USB drive, and any other drive, the mounting information is located within `/etc/fstab` (Raspbian). You may [view the manpage on fstab](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/fstab.5.html) to learn the details of its contents. This file will allow you to control the mounting behavior if you require any specific configuration.